# Visual studio debug is showing ‘Start’ instead of browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I cloned an Asp.Net MVC project from Github and I renamed it following the steps on this article https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/697108/Visual-Studio-Painlessly-Renaming-Your-Project-and
After that I rebuilt the solution and somehow visual studio doesn’t recognize my app as a web app anymore. The debug button used to show my default browser “google chrome” and when I hit F5 it used to open up in google chrome. Now the debug button shows “Start” and when I hit F5 to run, a dialog box pops up “A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly.  In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project” 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you must choose property "Set as StartUp Project" on your project.

Right click on your project -> Choose [Set as StartUp Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NbUj.png)